# How can I determine the potential nature of goods in an economy, given that they are perfect substitute?

Tags: giffen-goods, perfect-substitutes

Question:
There are a total of 5 different goods produced and consumed in the economy. Two of these goods, X and Y, are perfect substitutes. Which of the following statements are true?

1. X can be a normal good
2. X can be an inferior good
3. X can be a Giffen good

My attempt:
I tried to think about XED, but it did not seems to relate to normal, inferior and Giffen goods. I also considered indifference curve but it did not yield any result as well. The answer is (1) and (2), but I have no clues about how to approach this question.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi! Do you know a definition for "*perfect substitute*" and "*Giffen good*"?

Comment: @Giskard I think I do. Perfect substitute is basically two goods that are perfectly interchangable (so people will always choose the cheaper one). A Giffen good is a type of good where the negative income effect outweights the substitution effect. So do you mean that when price of X decreases, the demand of X must increase, so it can not possibly be a Giffen Good?

Comment: You could be a bit more rigorous, but that's the essential idea.

Comment: O, OK, thank you very much! I am still a high school student, so I don't really know much about rigorous definitions/formula for economic concepts. Do you have any recommendations for economic textbooks? (I probably will major economics in university) Again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am very much in the minority with my opinion but I would recommend choosing a different major.

Comment: If you insist on majoring in economics (your life, your choice), there are [several book recommendation questions on this SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=book) that you can browse.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your advice. I will consider it thoroughly before next year's application.